# Before loading ubuntu home page 'command not found' error

Tags: bashrc

As I login to my user name 'hp', I am getting following error message

[image: Error message print screen before loading ubuntu 16.04 home page]

I am also attaching .profile print screen to give complete details.

[image: .profile details]

Request you to please help me. I am newbee to ubuntu and this problem is hitting hard.

Comment: Does your ~/.profile have DOS line endings? what is the output of `file ~/.profile` ?

Comment: Please paste the contents and error messages as text here if possible. Screenshots are badly accessible for text.

Comment: @steeldriver, when I run command 'file ~/.profile'. I am getting following output -- '/home/hp/.profile: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text'

Comment: @ByteCommander, i am getting following message "Error found when loading /homehp/.profile: /home/hp/.profile: line 1: #: command not found. As a result the session will not be configured correctly . You should fix the problem as soon as feasible."

Comment: Initially I was not facing this issue. I tried to install mongo db and as part of that added one more line at the end of .profile page and it was 'export PATH = /home/hp/mongo..../bin:$PATH' for mongo db & the system started throwing this error message. Therefore now I have removed path of mongo db now and still getting this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining the type of your `.profile` with the `file` command identified it as:

```
UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
```

The problem is this `BOM`. It stands for "Byte Order Mark" and is three extra bytes at the beginning of a stream/document, which can indicate the kind of unicode encoding that is used. It is discouraged for UTF-8 though and not valid in shell scripts.

Probably you got this by using an inappropriate editor to modify your file, e.g. some Windows software.

To fix your problem, you have to remove this BOM again. [How can I remove the BOM from a UTF-8 file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381230/103151) contains a couple useful suggestions how you can do that. One possible way would be to run this command:

```
sed -i '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' ~/.profile
```

In simple words, this checks if the file's first line starts with these three BOM bytes and removes those.

Comment: your solution proved a silver bullet. Could you please suggest the best way to update .profile file with 'export PATH'.

Comment: @Deepak Just like the line you already see at the end of that file. Copy this and replace the middle part with your new location, like `PATH=/some/where:$PATH`. Using e.g. `gedit` as editor should be fine.